# Does the sequence have a uniform limit? How do I show this?

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, limits, continuity

I am having problems with the following exercise, I already did part $(i)$ and $(ii)$, I am having problems with $(iii)$.

**Exercise:**

Let
$ \large f_n(x)=\left\{
                \begin{array}{ll}
                  1 ~~~if~~x = 0  \\
                  n\sin(\frac{x}{n}) ~~~if~~0<x\leq 1
                \end{array}
              \right.
  $

$\large (iii)$ Does the sequence have a uniform limit?

I do not how to proceed. My professor gave me a hint: $$0 \leq x- n \sin(x/n) \leq 1- n\sin(1/n) \text{ if } x \in [0,1].$$ How do I use this hint? Can I use my pointwise limit and say that if the uniform limit exists then it's equal to the pointwise limit?

---

**These are the exercies I have solved. If you see any mistakes please let me know.**

$\large (i)$ Prove that each $f_n$ is discontinous at $x=0$.

Let $\left\{a_k\right\}_{k \geq 1}$ \in (0,1] be a sequence where $a_k \to 0$ as $k \to \infty$ In order to show that $f_n$ is discontinous at $x=0$ all I need to do is to show that

$$\lim_{k \to \infty} f_n (a_k) \neq 1$$

we have

$$\lim_{k \to \infty} \left( n\sin(\frac{a_k}{n})\right) = 0 \neq 1$$

thus $f_n$ is discontinous at $x=0$.

$\large (ii)$ Prove that the sequence has a pointwise limit.

$p(x) = \lim_{n \to \infty}\left( f_n(x) \right)$

I found the pointwise limit for when $x = 0$ and $x \in (0,1]$ :

$ \large p(x)=\left\{
                \begin{array}{ll}
                  1 ~~~if~~x = 0  \\
                  0 ~~~if~~0<x\leq 1
                \end{array}
              \right.
  $

best regards

Husky

Comment: shouldn't $p(x) = x$ for $x\ne 0$? otherwise the hint won't make sense.

Comment: @user251257 The hint makes sense because we need to find a supremum.

Comment: for a fixed $x\in (0,1]$ applies l'hopital's rule on the limit of $y \sin(x/y)$ for $y\to \infty$ yields $x$, not $0$. your $p(x)$ is wrong.

Comment: But its not $y \to \infty$ its $x \to 0$? @user251257

Comment: $y$ replaces $n$, as l'hopital is about functions on reals.

Comment: other way to see it, for large $n$, we have $\sin(x/n) \approx x/n$.

Comment: You are right! Sorry! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We have (using the hint)

$$\sup_{x\in[0,1]}|f_n(x)-p(x)|\le 1-n\sin\left(\frac1n\right)\xrightarrow{n\to\infty}0$$
so the sequence $(f_n)$ converges uniformly to $p$ on $[0,1]$.

Comment: Thank you very much! Do you have time to go through (i) and (ii) and let me know if I did something wrong?

Comment: You're correct in (i) and (ii), just (I think) you should mention  that you used the result $\lim\limits_{y\to0}\frac{\sin y}{y}=1$ to answer the two questions.

Comment: Okay, thank you very much!

Comment: @user235783 Could you perhaps check if my point wise limit is correct? Another user is stating that the I should have $p(x) =x$ for $x \ne 0$. Which doesn't really make sense to me

Comment: @Husky653 Yes $p(x)=x$ for $x\ne0$ because
$$\lim_{n\to\infty}n\sin(x/n)=x\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{\sin(x/n)}{\frac xn}=x\lim_{y\to0}\frac{\sin y}{y}=x$$